Clang AST Matchers: how to find function with specific name?
I try to match all expressions that call to std::sort, so I wrote code like this

Unfortunately, the check function of this class is not called.
I also tried AddMatcher code like this:

but it still didn't take effect. Here is my test code:

I tried to search the official documentation, but I can't seem to find the reason for the failure.
I hope to match all std::sort call statements.
enter image description here
I tried to generate the ast of my test file, and it really couldn't match FuncDecl, but I couldn't figure out why there was an ImplicitCastExpr, and std::sort was still in this castExpr, as shown above.

The matcher itself is fine, and successfully matches calls to std::sort.  You can use clang-query to test the matcher by itself.  Since the problem is not with the match expression, I suggest you edit the question to include a complete (compilable, runnable) program demonstrating the problem.  Also please specify which version of Clang you are using, and replace the image the text it contains.

thanks, I will edit my question right now.

I solved this problem. This is because I did not install the clang-16 package, which caused clang compilation to fail without performing this clang-tidy check.
Just execute shell: "export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include".
What is confusing is that other bugprobes can take effect, but this bugprobe does not work.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
